# Function to pick a seemingly random index from an array<string>

Tags: c++, arrays, string, random

I'm having a problem figuring out how to pick a random index from an `array<string>`.

It's for a card game. Instead of shuffling the deck I wanna use the srand function, inside a function to seemingly pick a random number. But every thing that I try just fails.

Here is part of the array:

> **array<string, 52> cards = { "Ess \3", "Ess \4", "Ess \5", "Ess \6","2 \3","2 \4" };**

The **\3 \4 \5 \6** is the symbols of the cards, for example Hearts, Diamond, Spades.

Anyway.. I just wanna pick a seemingly random index of the 52.
When I think I'm getting close I run in to something like this:
"C++ no suitable constructor exists to convert from int to basic_string" something like that.

And I don't get it. I have tried for a very long time. Please help me.

My latest attempt...

```
string randindex = rand() % 52;
cout << cards[randindex];
```

This is of course not working for me. Before creating a function i first have to learn how to pick a random index...

Comment: Please show what you attempted to do.

Comment: I would recommend [`std::uniform_int_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_int_distribution) instead of `srand`

Comment: `rand() % 52` returns an integer, and thus cannot be stored in a string. Store as an integer, then use the integer as the index into the array. Also, using a modern random engine should be preferred over rand.

Comment: okay, that make sense.. now i have a few thing to try and look up.. thank you

Comment: Please note that function `rand()` is only kept in the C++ library for compatibility with ancient source files. For modern C++ random number generation, use the `<random>` header file. For full details, see the [official N3551 paper](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3551.pdf)

Comment: Quimby, that is interesting! i will look in to that, i like what im seeing, random, min , max etc...

Comment: Haa okej jpmarinier. Im a student and my teacher suggest using srand, probably because its easier?

Comment: @gunnar20008 Yes, it is a quick fix. Unfortunately a lot of C++ teachers teach pre-C++2011 legacy stuff because it makes things *momentarily* easier. This is a [very common complaint](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YnWhqhNdYyk). The lady in the Youtube video explains that in great detail. Good luck with C++ !

Comment: @gunnar20008 As the Original Poster (OP) of this question, if you found the answer provided by ABacker useful, you are supposed to upvote and/or accept it. Thanks ! This is part of the feedback part of the process. See [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
int index = rand() % 52;
string card = cards[index];
```

Use card variable as you wish.

Comment: Man.. that is working.. what the... thank you! Can you imagine i tried for hours to solve this? i was close! i tip toed around the solution!!! I have so much on my mind.. I just learned functions, array, data structures and more, its a lot on my mind..

Comment: I know your feelings, I was at your position years ago,  Good luck.